# Why is my program not comparing return values in an if, elif, else statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, return

The problem I am having is that even if Point M is shorter to P than Point M or vice-versa, the program only prints that they are the same distance. Could this be a problem with my return values? or with the if, elif, else statements?

```
import math
print("This Program takes the coordinates of two points (Point M and N) and uses the distance formula to find which "
      "point is closer to Point P (-1, 2).")

x_P = -1
y_P = 2

def main():
    x_1 = int(input("Enter an x coordinate for the first point: "))
    y_1 = int(input("Enter an x coordinate for the first point: "))
    x_2 = int(input("Enter an x coordinate for the second point: "))
    y_2 = int(input("Enter an x coordinate for the second point: "))
    distance(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)
    distance1 = 0
    distance2 = 0
    if distance1 < distance2:
        print("Point M is closer to Point P.")
    elif distance1 > distance2:
        print("Point N is closer to Point P.")
    else:
        print("Points M and N are the same distance from Point P.")


def distance(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2):
    distance1 = math.sqrt((x_P - x_1) ** 2 + (y_P - y_1) ** 2)
    distance2 = math.sqrt((x_P - x_2) ** 2 + (y_P - y_2) ** 2)
    return distance1, distance2


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `return` values, so instead of

```
distance(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)
distance1 = 0
distance2 = 0
```

You should use

```
distance1, distance2 = distance(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
distance(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)
distance1 = 0
distance2 = 0
```

Your call to distance() doesn't have anything to apply the return values to, so they, essentially, disappear.  The distance1 and distance2 in the distance() function are local to the namespace of the function itself.  Even if they weren't, you would be overwriting them with the distance1 = 0 and distance2 = 0 statements.

Easy fix:

```
(distance1, distance2) = distance(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)
```

Since your function returns a tuple, just accept the tuple with your variables in the main namespace.

Oh, and all of your inputs ask for x values.